# Accessing and working with std::vector from multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector

I have a vector that I would like to access and work with from multiple threads. I have created an example below to illustrate the functionality that I would like to accomplish.

The goals are to be (1) high speed, (2) thread safe, and (3) **if possible** continue to use vectors as my larger project uses vectors all over the place and as such I would like to maintain that.

However, if I need to switch from vectors to something else then I am open to that as well.

The following example below compiles but crashes rather quickly because it is not thread safe.

Any ideas on how I can fix the example below which I can then apply to my larger project?

Thank you:

```
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <atomic>
#include <algorithm>

enum EmployeeType {

    HOURLY = 0,
    SALARIED = 1,
    COMMISSION = 2,
    OTHER = 3

};

enum EmployeePosition {

    SalesPerson = 0,
    Cashier = 1,
    Stocker = 2,
    Janitor = 3,
    AssistantManager = 4,
    Manager = 5,
    GeneralManager = 6,
    Owner = 7

};

class Employee;

class Employee {

private:

    float _TotalCostPerYear;
    EmployeeType _TypeOfEmployee;
    EmployeePosition _PositionOfEmployee;

protected:

public:

    Employee() :_TotalCostPerYear(0.0f), _TypeOfEmployee(EmployeeType::HOURLY),
        _PositionOfEmployee(EmployeePosition::SalesPerson){};

    float GetTotalCost() { return _TotalCostPerYear; }
    void SetTotalCost(float ValueToSet) { _TotalCostPerYear = ValueToSet; }

    EmployeeType GetEmployeeType() { return _TypeOfEmployee; }
    void SetEmployeeType(EmployeeType ValueToSet) { _TypeOfEmployee = ValueToSet; }

    EmployeePosition GetEmployeePosition() { return _PositionOfEmployee; }
    void SetEmployeePosition(EmployeePosition ValueToSet) { _PositionOfEmployee = ValueToSet; }

};

std::vector <Employee> AllEmployees;

std::thread* AddEmployeesThread;
std::thread* RemoveEmployeesThread;
std::thread* CalculateEmploymentCostsThread;
std::thread* PrintTotalsThread;

std::atomic<bool> ContinueProcessing = true;
std::atomic<float> TotalSalaryCosts = 0.0f;

std::uniform_int_distribution<int>* RandDistTypeOfEmployee;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int>* RandDistPositionOfEmployee;
std::uniform_real_distribution<float>* RandDistSalaryOfEmployee;

std::mt19937* RandomNumberGenerator;

time_t rawtime;
struct tm timeinfo;

void RandomAddEmployees();
void RandomRemoveEmployees();
void CalculateEmployementCosts();
void PrintTotals();

void RandomAddEmployees() {

    while (ContinueProcessing) {

        Employee NewEmployee;

        NewEmployee.SetEmployeePosition((EmployeePosition)(*RandDistPositionOfEmployee)(*RandomNumberGenerator));
        NewEmployee.SetEmployeeType((EmployeeType)(*RandDistTypeOfEmployee)(*RandomNumberGenerator));
        NewEmployee.SetTotalCost((*RandDistSalaryOfEmployee)(*RandomNumberGenerator));

        AllEmployees.push_back(NewEmployee);

    }

}

void RandomRemoveEmployees() {

    while (ContinueProcessing) {

        EmployeePosition PositionToRemove = (EmployeePosition)(*RandDistPositionOfEmployee)(*RandomNumberGenerator);

        static const auto is_position_erasable = [&PositionToRemove](Employee& E) { return E.GetEmployeePosition() == PositionToRemove; };

        AllEmployees.erase(std::remove_if(AllEmployees.begin(), AllEmployees.end(), is_position_erasable), AllEmployees.end());

        EmployeeType TypeToRemove = (EmployeeType)(*RandDistTypeOfEmployee)(*RandomNumberGenerator);

        static const auto is_type_erasable = [&TypeToRemove](Employee& E) { return E.GetEmployeeType() == TypeToRemove; };

        AllEmployees.erase(std::remove_if(AllEmployees.begin(), AllEmployees.end(), is_position_erasable), AllEmployees.end());

    }

}

void CalculateEmployementCosts() {

    while (ContinueProcessing) {

        float RunningTotal = 0.0f;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < AllEmployees.size(); ++i) {

            RunningTotal += AllEmployees[i].GetTotalCost();

        }

        TotalSalaryCosts = RunningTotal;

    }

}

void PrintTotals() {

    while (ContinueProcessing) {

        time(&rawtime);
        localtime_s(&timeinfo, &rawtime);

        if ((timeinfo.tm_sec % 5) == 0) {

            std::cout << "\n\nIn total there are " << AllEmployees.size() << " employees with a total cost of " << TotalSalaryCosts << " to the company.";

        }

    }

}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    time(&rawtime);
    localtime_s(&timeinfo, &rawtime);

    RandomNumberGenerator = new std::mt19937((unsigned int)timeinfo.tm_sec);
    RandDistTypeOfEmployee = new std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(0, 3);
    RandDistPositionOfEmployee = new std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(0, 7);
    RandDistSalaryOfEmployee = new std::uniform_real_distribution<float>(35000.0f, 300000.0f);

    std::cout << "Welcome to the crude employment simulation program. Press enter to get started.";
    std::cout << "\n\nNote that once the program starts you can press any key to stop the simulation.\n";

    std::cin.get();

    AddEmployeesThread = new std::thread(RandomAddEmployees);
    RemoveEmployeesThread = new std::thread(RandomRemoveEmployees);
    CalculateEmploymentCostsThread = new std::thread(CalculateEmployementCosts);
    PrintTotalsThread = new std::thread(PrintTotals);

    std::cin.get();

    std::cout << "\n\nExiting the simulation.";

    ContinueProcessing = false;

    AddEmployeesThread->join();
    RemoveEmployeesThread->join();
    CalculateEmploymentCostsThread->join();
    PrintTotalsThread->join();

    delete AddEmployeesThread;
    delete RemoveEmployeesThread;
    delete CalculateEmploymentCostsThread;
    delete PrintTotalsThread;

    delete RandDistSalaryOfEmployee;
    delete RandDistPositionOfEmployee;
    delete RandDistTypeOfEmployee;

}
```

Comment: Do you really need all those `new`s?

Comment: @NeilKirk Probably not; it was an example and I am just used to using C++ this way. I could take them out and put them in my variable declaration section and it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to protect access to your `AllEmployees` variable so that only one thread can access it at any time. You can use a `std::mutex` for protection, locking it with a `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` where necessary. First, add this include file:

```
#include <mutex>
```

Next, define a mutex — you can add the following definition just above your `AllEmployees` variable:

```
std::mutex AllEmpMtx;
```

Then, in all functions that access or modify `AllEmployees`, lock the mutex before any such operation, like this:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(AllEmpMtx);
```

For example, in the `RandomAddEmployees` function, you should add the `lock_guard` just above the call to `AllEmployees.push_back(NewEmployee)`.

When the `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` instance goes out of scope, its destructor will unlock the mutex.

By the way, you seem to be using scoped enumerations for `EmployeeType` and `EmployeePosition`. The C++11 standard requires them to be defined with `enum class`, not just `enum`.